# Revive Adserver mp4 video ad with html5 video player

Tags: html, firefox, video

I am using revive add server mp4 video ad, my problem here is, Revive add server mp4 video ad not working in firefox with html5 player. but it is working chrome and IE browser.

Actually mp4 video is not compatible in firefox, only a webm vedio allowed in firefox with html5 player.

I dont know how to play revive mp4 video ad on firefox with html5 player.

My code to get revive ad's:

```
 'apiAddress': 'http://site/revive-adserver/www/delivery/fc.php?script=bannerTypeHtml:vastInlineBannerTypeHtml:vastInlineHtml&zones=pre-roll:0.0-0%3D'+zon+'%7Cmid-roll:1.0-0%3D'+zon+'%7Cpost-roll:2.0-0%3D'+zon+'&nz=1&source=&r=R0.8364616059698164&block=0&format=vast&charset=UTF-8'
```

Can anyone help me??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you either request a different banner in FF, or if you're serving the video deliver webm when you get the request for an mp4 with the FF UA string

Comment: Yes exactly i have to request another video file if it is firefox..But i dont know how to request a webm file if it ff

Comment: replace your ad code when the request comes from FF (or better than useragent test use the canPlay function to explicitly check for mp4 or webm and if both fail fall back to a static banner)